# Can we merge multiple update sql into one sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of update sql as below:

```
UPDATE variable SET type='aa1' WHERE type='aaa';
UPDATE variable SET type='x1' WHERE type='bbb';
UPDATE variable SET type='da1' WHERE type='ccc';
UPDATE variable SET type='ac1' WHERE type='ddd';
-- more update sql
```

Since there are many sqls but they looks same,I am wondering can we merge it into one sql such as below:

```
UPDATE variable SET type=? WHERE type=?;
```

I know we can use `CASE WHEN`,but the solution seems ugly,is there more elegant way to do it?(Maybe key value mapping?)

```
   -- I do not want to do it like this
    UPDATE variable
     SET type=
      (
        CASE WHEN type='aa1' THEN 'aaa'
        CASE WHEN type='x1' THEN 'bbb'
       END
      )
     WHERE type IN('aa1','x1');
```

Also I know we can use some program language such as `jdbc` to do it,but I want to find if there is a pure sql solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you executing this from some programming language, or just out some some MySQL command line / query tool?

Comment: @Mureinik Mysql command line

Comment: you could created a MySQL function and then use that .. ?

Comment: @treyBake `function` is a choice,but I do not have the privilege to do it,I just wonder a sql solution

Comment: @lucumt ah I see :/ that's pretty much all the MySQL knowledge I can give haha - sorry! :)

Comment: I am afraid it won't possible by using sql, perhaps using sql procedures

Comment: If u can not create sql procedure or function, maybe create a bash or python script to handle it

Comment: @HRgiger I have already wrote in my question that **I am wonder if there is a pure sql solution**,bash or python script is similar to write program

Comment: Your example marked `-- I do not want to do it like this` would not even work anyway. For a start the values are back to front compared to your original (in the case statement you're testing for the existence of e.g. `aa1` and then setting the value to `aaa` ...but in the first version you were doing the exact opposite. Anyway...assuming you get the values right, this is your only real alternative in pure SQL, but there's no advantage to this method - it doesn't reduce the quantity of code, and it's much less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE variable v JOIN
       (SELECT 'aa1' as newtype, 'aaa' as oldtype UNION ALL
        SELECT 'x1', 'bbb' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'da1', 'ccc' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ac1', 'ddd'
       ) v2
       ON v2.oldtype = v.type
    SET v.type = v2.newtype;
```